# Windows 10: screen does not wake-up from keyboard

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have a Windows 10 computer which does not reactivate the screen when a key is pressed on the keybord. I can do whatever with the keyboard, the screen does not wake-up.

Everything is ok when the mouse is moved, even very slightly.

This is only when the screen is sleeping and the computer is still awake.
Everything is ok when the computer is sleeping/hibernating/whatever. A key or a mouse clic restart everything.

I checked with `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` and I see the keyboard is activated (I have keyboard + mouse + network card).

I also disabled USB selective sleep, but no improvement.

What can I do to understand what's going on? And to solve this problem?

Comment: It's possible that your BIOS has a setting that also allows or disables the keyboard to wake the system. it could be overriding the OS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I cant ask comments until 50 points so, ill try the answer it might be:

Option 1:

- reset ALL the power profiles back to their default settings
- reboot
- then change the power profile back to your custom values.

Option 2: Win10 Creators update is/has issues with USB on some* machines. Roll it back if possible.

Option 3: I cant see if the kb is USB? If USB, try connecting the keyboard to a USB2.0 port.
*Random thought: i wonder if the kb itself takes sleep ques from the screen sleep time....*